# Why does R round natural logarithms as it does?

Tags: r, natural-logarithm

I was perplexed by the difference in R:

```
log(0.0001)/0.0001
-92103.4
```

and, e.g., Google calculator rendering:

```
 ln(0.0001)/0.0001
 -92103.4037198
```

why is the rounding so different?

Comment: I agree that the answer is valid also for this question, but the wording of the other question does not give that away immediately.

Comment: the down-voting lately is getting crazy. clear question, minimal reproducible example, and expected output. I get that you all are super duper smart and this is a basic question for you, but seriously put your adult pants on for once and stop down-voting questions into oblivion

Comment: Seconding what @rawr says. And upvoting to counteract it. This is a newish user you're downvoting. Doing so without helping them understand why is not a way to build community.

Comment: Also, I am asking why, not only how to fix it.  The question of why the default is set that only one decimal was not explained in the other answers, as far as I could see.  That said, I am not offended by the downvotes, it definitely is answered elsewhere, albeit worded a bit clumsily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increasing the **displayed** precision with, e.g.:

```
options(digits=20)
```

fixes the "problem"

```
> log(0.0001)/0.0001
[1] -92103.4
> options(digits=20)
> log(0.0001)/0.0001
[1] -92103.403719761816319
```

Note that the internal precision is always high and can be viewed with the `.Machine` variable:

```
> .Machine
#Many other details here
$double.digits
[1] 53
```

the foregoing indicates that the machine has a 53-bit [mantissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand), which indicates that [double-precision floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is being used for the calculations, which is standard.

Comment: Could also do `print(log(0.0001)/0.0001, digits = 20)` and not have to worry about changing any options.

Comment: I think it's worth being explicit that the difference is only in the way the result is printed, not the way it's calculated or stored. `x <- log(0.0001)/0.0001`, followed by a calculation using `x` (eg: `x * 1E6`) returns a higher precision result (eg: `-92103403720`) than the printed result of `x` would appear to allow.

Comment: @rosscova: I had noted it, but now stress it with additional information. I'd've been fine with you editing the answer as well :-)